# How to reference an Oracle Database an Azure instance of SQL Server: Can they be linked?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, azure, stored-procedures, etl

I want reference data residing on an Oracle server from within an Azure managed instance of SQL Server.  Oracle Server is not a cloud instance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database doesn't support linked servers. Azure SQL Database contains single database and managed instance. You can see here: [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).
[image]

So you can not create a linked Oracle Server for the Azure managed instance.

Other words, it's impossible to reference data residing on an Oracle server from within an Azure managed instance of SQL Server

Hope this can helps you.

Comment: That is _very_ useful but as I understand it then, the implication is that having SSIS available in Azure limits it to shuffling data between local tables and perhaps a file system.

Comment: Actually I believe its a lot more powerful than that although you cannot use linked servers you can (at a minimum) connect to on-premises SQL Server instances using domain credentials.  Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-connect-with-windows-auth?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Asher That's right, it's a  good choice. Using Azrue Data Factory is also a good way. In Azure Data Factory, you can use [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to copy data among data stores located on-premises and in the cloud. After the data is copied, it can be further transformed and analyzed. You can also use Copy Activity to publish transformation and analysis results for business intelligence (BI) and application consumption. Data Factory features are very powerful.

Comment: is this answer stil valid?